# Laptop Charger Failure during AC supply undervoltage

Tags: charger, laptop, undervoltage

My Laptop Charger is rated 240V AC Voltage. While plug in the outlet the undervoltage occurs (using multitester) the voltage is 107V. At that instant my charger is very hot, right now my charger is not working. What is the reason behind of Undervoltage to the Charger that cause overheating/damage?

Comment: Violating device ratings indeed can cause failure. Can you provide an image of your device's input/output rating label in your question? Not all AC/DC adapters are 90-264VAC "Universal" rated, as is evident from your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A laptop adapter is typically based on a switching converter, maybe a PFC front end and an LLC DC-DC regulator.

That means it is a constant power load.  As input voltage goes down, current goes up.

As current goes up, conduction losses (I^2R) increase.  In a properly designed charger, an under voltage condition will not cause damage due to several safeguards built in.

Usually there is an under voltage lockout which shuts the converter down if the input voltage is too low, and a thermal shutdown which shuts the converter down before damage occurs.

Does your charger start to work again when it cools off?

Comment: No, The Charger was totally damage I found some oily/sticky substance coming out from it last time. I have two damage charge MAC BOOK PRO and ASUS charger. Do you know @John D if this charger (in terms of brand) uses the voltage lockout phenomenon during undervoltage?

Comment: @JamesC: You need to stick to technical terms to avoid misunderstanding. "_The Charger was totally damage ..._" should probably read "The charger (small 'c') appears permanently damaged ..." as it is probably only one or two components that are damaged, not the 'total' power supply.

Comment: @John D: Thank you for that clarification. Do you know some charger that uses safeguards built in for undervoltage?

Comment: I have used many laptop "chargers" or power supply units. Several have died rather early and I blame the rather poor mains (brownouts) in combination with the climate here in West Africa. Sadly, even if only a few components are damaged, those power units do not open well (sealed) and I have never managed to repair one. If anybody has got experience with such repairs (by replacing with genuince components) please shout and I will open a fresh question.